# How to specify the compiler to cmake?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, cmake

On my Windows system, I have both gcc and Visual C++.

By default, cmake selects Visual C++.

How can I force it to use gcc?

How can I specify the compiler path?

In the CMakeLists.txt file I tried with:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
```

with no result.

Thank's.

Comment: Have you tried these methods: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F

Comment: @JavaCake: you are right. The FAQ seems to be more complete than the real documentation :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the generator:

```
cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" <path_to_your_project>
```

If gcc is in your path CMake will pick it automatically.